# How delete class from intent kotlin

Tags: android, class, kotlin, android-intent, compilation

I have broadcastReciever,which i registered in activity. I want to modify existing intent,to start activities with it,but i not understand,how i can delete class from my intent. When i try to do intent.setClass(applicationContext,null) i get compilation error: Null can not be a value of a non-null type Class. But how delete class from existing intent? It's very interesting for me,what class intent have when we create it using standard constructors of intent? Thanks everybody for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setClass` is a convenience function for looking up a component and calling `setComponent`. So you can call `setComponent(null)` to clear the component. An Intent does not have to have an associated component.

However, it is unusual to need to modify an intent that was already set up for some other task. I can't think of a reason why you would do this instead of creating a new Intent.

Comment: Sorry,but setting component to null not solve the problem,but empty intent with the same params works ok. But it very interesting for me,why intent from reciever impossible clear. Whether it issue of framework,which i should immediately report to google?

Comment: I don't know what problem it is you were seeing, so don't know if it was a bug. It seems unlikely something as trivial as setting null wouldn't work and would last as a bug for 10 years without anyone noticing.

Comment: Even without nulling component all works ok,if you will null a package,using intent.setPackage(null). So my question was solved.

Comment: Is this an intent you received when your Activity was created? That would explain why the component is already resolved to a package, so if that's the case it's not a bug. I don't think Intents are intended to be mutated and reused.

Comment: Not,it come to me in activity from broadcast receiver. I understood,what it's not bug.